# R: Search a vector from end forward

Tags: r

A newbie question here.  I have a vector v.  I would like to search the vector from the end forward to find the last instance a condition is true.  In matlab I would call find(condition, 1, 'last') and the search would start from the end of the vector and move forward.  Is there an equivalent call in R?

For instance, I might like to know the last time `v < v[length(v)]`.  I know that `max(which(v<v[length(v)]))` gives the correct answer.  However speed is important, and it seems as if this first returns all the indices meeting the condition v

Answer (score 4):

Generally in R it is preferred that you run a function "vectorized" on the entire vector, rather than in a loop that lets you stop as soon as a condition is true. However, the function `rev` will reverse a vector and might be handy for what you want to do.